# Automatically attach GDB to process with Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm writing a C++ application that runs within an environment. In Eclipse CDT I set up a debug configuration that attaches GDB to the application process. Unfortunately, I still have to manually select the process for every debug session. There is typically just one process with respective name but, of course, different process ID every launch.

Is there a way of automating this step, so that starting a debug session could be done optimally with one single mouse click?

Thanks very much,
  Ralph

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this (I hope someone does). In fact I had thought there was already a feature request for this, but I can't find it now. Perhaps you would be willing to contribute such a request on [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT&component=cdt-debug)?